Postgres password reset issue
I was trying to reset the password.
r9mzsy20=# ALTER USER 9mz_dba WITH PASSWORD '92837474';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "9"
LINE 1: ALTER USER 9mz_dba WITH PASSWORD '92837474..

For user u_9mz_rw and u_9mz_ro I was able to reset the password.
ALTER USER u_9mz_ro PASSWORD '92837474' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
ALTER USER u_9mz_rw PASSWORD '92837474' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';

But for this USER 9mz_dba I am getting an error.
Can anyone please help with that.
Here is a list of my users:


Try to add double quotes around the user name ALTER USER "9mz_dba" WITH PASSWORD '92837474'; From the Lexical structure: "SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (_)... Quoted identifiers can contain any character, except the character with code zero."

Try to add double quotes " around the user name:
ALTER USER "9mz_dba" WITH PASSWORD '92837474';

From the 4.1.1. Identifiers and Key Words:

SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (_)
...
Quoted identifiers can contain any character, except the character with code zero.

Which means it's perfectly fine to have a user/role identifier that doesn't start with a-z or underscore _, but to reference it, you need to wrap it in double-quotes.

Also, you lost the 3rd line of that error message with the caret ^ character, which should clarify it's pointing at the first 9 character, not the second one: demo
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "9"
LINE 2: ALTER USER 9mz_dba WITH PASSWORD '92837474';
                   ^

In PostgreSQL 15 and 16, the numeric literal processing was changed, which means the error message will change as well, trying and failing to interpret that as a number: demo
ERROR:  trailing junk after numeric literal at or near "9m"
LINE 2: ALTER USER 9mz_dba WITH PASSWORD '92837474';
                   ^


Usernames which start with digits need to be quoted.
ALTER USER "9mz_dba" WITH PASSWORD '1234687';


Perhaps you can improve the quality of the answer by explaining why, pointing to the documentation and explaining that that is not only about leading digits.

This answer explains it much better, but it's not quite a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27318809/4989143
